# Find out why a file matched an Microsoft 365 Content Search query

Tags: microsoft-office-365, content-management

I am learning about [Content Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/ediscovery-content-search) in Microsoft 365. I've studied Microsoft's documentation, Googled and searched here, but I can't find an answer to what feels like a basic question.

When I execute a query over some SharePoint files with this KQL:

```
SensitiveType:“U.K. national health service number”|1..|85.. (c:s) SensitiveType:“Credit card number”|1..|85.. (c:s) SensitiveType:“U.K. electoral roll number”|1..|85.. (c:s)
```

In the exported results it returns files as I would expect, but with no indication about why each file matched the KQL statement. Some of these files are very large multi-tab spreadsheets.

How can I find out which part(s) of the KLQ statement matched, how many times, and at what point in the files, please?

Without that information, it's hard for me to ask the owner of the file to examine it and assess the data risk. I intend to include many more sensitive types in the KQL in the future, so splitting it to have just one type per query wouldn't be great, and even then I'd not know where in the file to look.